# passwordless sudo still requires password in capistrano

Tags: ruby, capistrano

In capistrano script

```
set :stage, :production
set :branch, 'master'
server 'lion.example.jp', user: 'ubuntu', roles: %w(app), 
set :user, "ubuntu"

namespace :deploy do
    desc 'Collec Static Files'
    task :collectImg do
        on roles(:app) do
            execute :sudo,"curl -X GET --unix-socket /run/control.unit.sock http://localhost/control/applications/myapp/restart"

        end
    end
    after :publishing, :collectImg
end
```

it shows error below

```
DEBUG [7fade908]    sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
```

However I set passwordless `sudo` for user `ubuntu`

Why does it still require password?

Or can I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure that you set ubuntu group to password less?

Can you double check that your settings look like this for ubuntu user


`deploy ALL=NOPASSWD:/etc/init.d/mysqld, /etc/init.d/apache2`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the "ubuntu" user in capistrano, like so.

I see that it's in the server block, but maybe give this a try as well.

```
set :user, "ubuntu"
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment I added this line and update the article. however in vain.